# change background color of the layout in Android

Tags: android

I have a simple Android application, with 3 buttons. When i click on the 1st button, i wanna change the background color of the layout (which is now white... i wanna change in other color, when i press the button). How can i do this?

On that button, i have a myClickHndler event

```
    public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button01:
        text.setText("Button 1 was clicked");
        break;
    case R.id.Button03:
        //text.setText("Button 3 was clicked");
                    .................... // ?
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, when i click on the 3rd button i wanna change the color, not on the 1st button.. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Give an Id to your `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/laidout"
        ...>
```

and then from your java class say:

```
...
case R.id.Button03:
//text.setText("Button 3 was clicked");
  .................... // ?
mlayout= findViewById(R.id.laidout);
// set the color 
mlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHATEVER);
// you can use setBackgroundResource() and pass appropriate ID
// if you want a drawable bundled as resource in the background
mlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_img);
break;
...
```

[EDIT]: added code for thing requested in comment

Comment: Ok, thanks! And if i wanan change the background of the layout with a .png image, how can i do this? Is it possible? I have a png image in res/drawable folder, and i wanna show as the background for the layout. 
Regards,

Comment: yes you can do that..I have added code in my post above. Check it out.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in some cases. The call to findViewById(R.id.laidout) throws a RuntimeException when made within either onCreate or onResume (not sure about other places).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the background dynamically, use

```
 YourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

Answer (score 1):

setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated

Try the following simple code...

Working Code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backrepeat_blue);
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code...

Code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); 
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.GameLayout);
linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Hope this helps.