# how to change background in android layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to know how i can change my Layout Background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in layout tag in your xml file write

```
android:background="@drawable/image">
```

and put image.jpg(gif,bmp,png) on drawable folder

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, it can be done via XML...

- [`android:background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) XML attritube.  This can use a drawable in the form of `"@drawable/imagefile"` or a color value `"#FF000000"`.

or perform the color change programmatically with the following functions:

- [`setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29): Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.
- [`setBackgroundColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29): Sets the background color for this view.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: You can set layout color as well as an image to it.

[change background color of the layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895367/change-background-color-of-the-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Configure background programmatically in Kotlin language:

```kotlin
    val mainLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.mainLayout)
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentColor)
```

You can change the ConstraintLayout to whatever Layout you want.