# Cannot set background image in android

Tags: android, background

I am trying to change my background image. I thought i was doing something wrong so i searched for the answer and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650950/how-to-change-background-in-android-layout)

My code does exactly as the answer suggest however it does not work. I can easily alter the color of the background, but when I try to place a background image it fails. My jpg (480X800) resource is in the drawable-hdpi. I tried changing resolution to 800x480.

So far i only edited the activity_main.xml and added some resources:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/vertical_lines"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_lines" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried setting android:fillViewport="true" in the root layout? Also, try to only set the root layout without any child views and check what happens. Maybe some inner view is causing the issue.

Comment: thanks i tried fillViewport="true" and it didnt work. I will try deleting the children.

Comment: ok when i delete children in xml and remove errors in the main (by deleting the code that corresponds to them) I get a crash when a application starts stating: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: have u tried cleaning the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem wasnt with my code at all. I have used photoshop and for some reason the jpg file was saved in the CMYK color mode. After i switched the setting to RBG and resaved the file as png everything works fine. I cant believe i spend so much time on this when the problem wasnt even in my code. Hopefully this will save someones time if they run into similar problem.