# Android. Change the background color of a FrameLayout from code

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I'm trying to change the background color of a FramyLayout.
The color is changing, but to the wrong one.

However it is working fine if I do it through the XML.

Here is my res/values/colors.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="grey">#888888</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="red">#ffff3448</color>
    <color name="green">#ff408c3a</color>
</resources>
```

Here is how it looks like if I make changes in the XML
    
[image: Colors changed correctly]

And that's what is happening if I try to do it with the code

```
 FrameLayout frameLayoutBalance = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutBalance);
 frameLayoutBalance.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);
```

[image: Colors changed incorrectly]

Comment: look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895367/change-background-color-of-the-layout-in-android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not use 
frameLayoutBalance.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);

setBackgroundColor required a Color (i.e. its value as describe by Chirag Raval) not a color resources.

use this frameLayoutBalance.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

Answer (score 3):

Use this code 
frameLayoutBalance.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00aacc"));

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot for a fast response. Even though your code is working and can be used as a workaround, I'm afraid it can't be used as a solution. It is always a best practice to do not hardcore any values as if they change I will need to go through all code and change it manually everywhere.

Comment: frameLayoutBalance.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));