# Change layout background button press

Tags: android, background

I have a button that if you hold down the phone vibrates, and if it passes 1.5 seconds changes the background color.
But I want that when pressed  first button change the color green, and if pressed a second time to change to red, and so on with the times the button is pressed.

**My code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static int MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA = 1500;
    private RelativeLayout mealLayout;
    private ToggleButton toggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mealLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);  
        final Vibrator vibrator;
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(MainActivity.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                esperarYCerrar(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(1500);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    vibrator.cancel();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void esperarYCerrar(int milisegundos) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // acciones que se ejecutan tras los milisegundos
                finalizarApp();
                cambiarcolor();
            }
        }, milisegundos);
    }

    /**
     * Finaliza la aplicación
     */
    public void finalizarApp() {
        mealLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    public void cambiarcolor() {
        ToggleButton button=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        if (button.isChecked())
            mealLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            mealLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the two colors do not work, only works a color, I want to know how to make each time you press the button put a different color, red and green.

Comment: Ok that's what it does. But what is the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2895650/5456493 tell if it is working or not ?

Comment: Do you want to change Button's background when you click on it?

Comment: The problem is that the two colors do not work, only works a color, I want to know how to make each time you press the button put a different color, red and green.

Comment: color not changing is this your problem? or you want to change color alternatively that not working?

Comment: Im not sure what the issue is? You want to change the background for the BUTTON to green when pressed, and then when pressed again you want the button background to change to red, and vice versa?

Comment: Yes DadoZolic! but instead of the color of the button, the background color of the layout

Answer (score 0):

In your listener:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
....
ColorDrawable color = (ColorDrawable) yourView.getBackground();
int colorId = color.getColor();

if(colorId == Color.GREEN)
   mealLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
else if(colorId == Color.RED)
   mealLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
else
   //If not green or red set an optional color
....
```

Try this. Only thing I'm not sure about is the comparison with colorId and Color.x. You might need to compare this in a different way. Try to log the colorId to see what it gets you and from there find a proper way to compare it to some color Color.x.

You could also create a boolean and in your listener check if it is false: set background to green and set the boolean to true. Same thing if boolean is true: set background to red and boolean to false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I have solved so:

```
 if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                esperarYCerrar(MILISEGUNDOS_ESPERA);
                vibrator.vibrate(1500);
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                vibrator.cancel();
            }
```

Thank you for all DadoZolic.
I want to know one last thing, apart from changing the background, it is easy to add a different image?

Comment: Different image where? Instead of colors (RED and GREEN) you want to change the background to an image (meaning set the mealLayout background to an image) ?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I managed to do it, just add:             mimagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagen1);

I wonder if you work as a programmer for android?

Comment: Perfect, Because Sometimes I have trouble scheduling, and some things can not get to make, and I want to pay an expert programmer to do the job, if you are interested you can contact me and what price you charge per hour.

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity but I have to say no. Because first of all I don't see myself as an expert in Android and second I already have a full time job in development so I would probably not have the time for other work, but again thanks